# how to have a variable inside a variable in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to push a property file template like the below

```
schema.registry.url=http://{{ schemaregis_host{{ 
play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) }} }}:8081
```

I pass extra variables like these in the ansible input command

```
schemaregis0=host1
schemaregis1=host2

[inventory-hosts]
server1
server2
```

I want server1 property file to have the `schemaregis0=host1` and server2 to have the other.

Ansible doesn't like the variable within a variable. How can i get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the variables with dynamic name by accessing the `vars` dict:

```
schema.registry.url=http://{{ vars['schemaregis' + play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname)|string] }}
```

But if you want to set different values for each host, the best way is to use [host_vars configuration folder](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data)

Comment: It did not like it. "AnsibleError: Unexpected templating type error occurred"

Comment: Updated my answer to add typing of the index into string